# How to update a list column in pandas dataframe with a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume that you have a pandas dataframe with a **list column**.

How to append the **list column** based on a condition so that at the end we can get unique elements of list in that column?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2'])
print(df)

col1 = 'A'
df = df.append({'col1': col1, 'col2': ['a1','a2', 'a3']}, ignore_index=True)
print(df)

new_list = ['a4', 'a5','a1']
df.loc[df['col1'] == col1,'col2'][0].extend(new_list)
print(df)
```

Get

```
  col1          col2
0    A  [a1, a2, a3]
  col1                      col2
0    A  [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]
```

instead of

```
   col1          col2 
 0    A  [a1, a2, a3]   
   col1           col2 
 0    A  [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try leverage setsenter code here

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x:[*{*x}.union({*new_list})])
```

Output

```
col1                  col2
0    A  [a1, a5, a2, a3, a4]
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. You are converting x and new_list into sets and taking union. I couldn't find a correct syntax to make this union in python. Why do you have double stars for x?

Comment: {*x}-{*removal_list} -these astericks unpack the elements. The additional astericks unpacks the elements for the function to operate on them

Comment: Since I have a condition then it should be as follows:                          df.loc[df['col1'] == col1,'col2'] = df.loc[df['col1'] == col1,'col2'].apply(lambda x:[*{*x}.union({*new_list})])